# Adding multiple userform controls at runtime

Tags: vba

I have created a userform with a static label to instruct the user to check certain part numbers. The form will also have a static button to submit the input. However, I need the checkboxes to be made at runtime since it won't be certain how many checkboxes there will be every time the form is shown. There would be a max of twelve boxes, but most of the time only one or two boxes would be needed and I'd prefer to show only what's needed instead of having blank checkboxes. I've made a for loop to add the boxes.

Currently I can add one checkbox to the form, but in the record I'm working with there are supposed to be three. Everything that I am seeing online about dynamically adding controls mainly pertains to adding events to the controls, but I don't need events, just the controls. Can anyone see what I need to add/change in my code:

```
Private WithEvents chkbox As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
For i = 1 To 12
    If PNArray(i) Like "A*" And ChangeArray(i) = "New Part Number:" Then
        With Me.Controls
            Set chkbox = .Add("Forms.checkbox.1", "chkbox" & i, True)
            With chkbox
                .Width = 108
                .Height = 18
                .Top = 30 * i
                .Left = 54
                .Caption = PNArray(i)
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: `For i = 1 To 3` instead of to `12`?

Comment: If you know max checkboxes is 12, then just design it with 12, and then play in VBA with `Visible=True/False` or `Enable=True/false`

Comment: @Vityata There's a possibility of 12, but most likely only a few boxes will be needed. Or in my current case testing this, a box should be added at i = 1, 5, and 9. However, only the first is showing.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I could probably do that (and I think that I thought about doing that on Friday when I first started this task but since forgot). However, I'd like to learn this new approach to userforms and put it in my back pocket for future use. You should make an answer though, yours is a pretty good solution. :)

Comment: Step through your code and verify you are getting past the If statement.  It could be you are only adding 1 control.

Comment: @BrianMStafford It cycles through all 12 times and evaluates to true 3 times, as expected. I feel like this is a naming issue. I set chkbox multiple times (with the name dependent on the value of i) but I only have the one control variable to set. But then, I'd think that if it's because I just have 1, the checkbox would have the third caption not the first, so clearly I am missing something.

Comment: @LuxClaridge I'm not sure then what problem you have. Your code works perfectly. I tried it and it adds 3 checkboxes with no problems. Check image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G32Gx.jpg

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. The code works, it's just that when I was typing in the .top value (30 * i) I didn't think that i would be so different. For some reason I thought that top would be 30, then 60, then 90, but since i = 1, 3, and 5, top was 30, 90, and 150 while the userform was originally 80 tall. So now it's on to learning how to dynamically size the userform. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, the problem is `.Top=30*i`. You multiply always by index of array, when you want all checkboxes same distance. You need another variable to do that. Try like this:

```
Dim ZZ As Byte ' count of checkboxes
ZZ = 0

For i = 1 To 12
    If PNArray(i) Like "A*" And ChangeArray(i) = "New Part Number:" Then
        ZZ = ZZ + 1 'we increase count of checkboxes
        With Me.Controls
            Set chkbox = .Add("Forms.checkbox.1", "chkbox" & i, True)
            With chkbox
                .Width = 108
                .Height = 18
                .Top = 30 * ZZ 'we position the chekbox according to its rank (first one, second one, third one, and so on).
                .Left = 54
                .Caption = PNArray(i)
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

With this code, it does not matter how many checkboxes you have. It will add them in the right position, in a "podium" style

[image]